# How to remove revision part from bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I have the bibliography and main text as follows:

**reference.bib**

```
@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
@manual{freescale:33879A,
    organization  = "Freescale Semiconductor",
    title         = "Configurable Octal Serial Switch
                    with Open Load Detect Current Disable",
    year          =  2012,
    month         =  6,
    number        = "MC33879",
    note          = "Rev. 10.0"
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}

%\usepackage{cite}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editoria

\begin{document}

\section*{Acknowledgments}
This should be a simple paragraph before the References to thank those individuals and institutions who have supported your work on this article.
%
\newpage
%
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references.bib}

\vspace{11pt}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to remove `note = "Rev. 10.0"` in the reference above as I don't have information about that. 
 I tried to comment out by `% note = "Rev. 10.0"` but it gives me an error. How can I remove this part?

> You're missing a field name : : % note = "Rev. 10.0" (Error may have
> been on previous line)

Comment: Just change `note` to `mynote` (or any other field name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bibtex` ignores any field that is not a predefined one. Thus changing `note` to `mynote` (or any other name which is not a predefined `bibtex` field should do.

Comment: nice, not quite related but the format month and year above generate `6 2012` which looks a bit weird to me as there is no coma or something. Do you agree or have any suggestion? (not related but probably not worth a new question). EDIT: I just changed it to Feb and it looks good now.